# How to reference StartOutboundVoiceContact API attributes in Call Flow?

Tags: lambda, amazon-connect

When using the StartOutboundVoiceContact Connect API, I can't get the attributes from the call flow afterwards.

from lambda the code look like this:

[image]

**Attributes: {"CustomerFirstName": "Paul Russell"},**

The API works as expected and the call gets executed but when referencing the attribute inside the used call flow, I can't get the name.

[image]

I can hear the "Hello" But can't get the attribute to work.

Could someone correct what Am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Attribute value can't contain spaces.Can include only alphanumeric, dash, and underscore characters.

**Attributes: {"CustomerFirstName": "Paul"},**

Additionally, I was missing an "S" for "AttributeS" under the text-to-speech box.

Regards,